# Can you install previously supported system updates after device has been discontinued?

Tags: updates, att

Last week I got a (used) Samsung Note20 Ultra with AT&T. It has Android 11, One UI 3.1 and Security Patch March 1, 2021. Although it is now discontinued, but it was upgradable to Android 13 and One UI 5. Can I still get those "old" updates that this phone was upgradable to?

If I try to update it, it says, "Software Update Interrupted. No updates are available for your device at this time. Please try again in 24 hours." It has been saying this for a week now.

Comment: Are you still an AT&T customer? I do remember that other users have talked about that AT&T restricts updates for their device to their network, so you won't be able to get an update if you have moved to another MNO or just via your home Wi-Fi.

Comment: I didn't know that when I bought it, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You would be able to get those updates over-the-air (by direct download onto the phone) if your network supplier (in this case, AT&T) still had them available on their servers. It appears AT&T have taken them down.

This is hardly surprising, since the device was discontinued in December 2021, and it would cost AT&T a little money to keep them available. They could reasonably expect that everyone who wanted them would have uploaded them by now.

Your best hope to get those updates now is to locate someone who downloaded and preserved them. Your odds of success are not high. The first place to ask is [XDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XDA_(website)).